# Is it possible for malloc(), called just after free() to return pointer pointing to same freed memory?

Tags: c, operating-system

I am writing an application which is continuously running in while(1) and waits for an interrupt (basically a RING) to decode the message. So when I successfully decode the message, i just need to print it and starts waiting for another interrupt (a new message).

I want to clear all the data structures before it starts a new message. So I just free the pointers and mallo them back. But when I did that, there were still some fields in the data structures containing old data. So I just used calloc() to zeroed out all the memory inorder to clear old data.

I know the memory freed by calling free is not return to OS straight away, it still lies in the pool of free memory but is it possible for malloc to return the same freed memory?

```
if(res){                               // If decoded successfully
        display_CID_info(cs, cs_data); // Display CallerID message
        free(cs);                      // Free the CID data structure
        free(cs_data);                 // Free message data structure

        /* Allocate Data structures again for next iteration */
        cs_data = malloc(sizeof(cid_data));
        cs = calloc(1, sizeof(*cid));
    }
```

Comment: Certainly, why not? If you want the memory cleared,memset() it yourself, or use calloc(). Memory freed by free() isn't returned to the OS at all, it is pooled.

Comment: Thats exactly what i thought, but just needed some confirmation. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you are detecting old data in the `malloc`ed data structures suggests that you are doing something wrong by reading it before it has been written.

Comment: Do not add C++ tag for C questions!

Comment: @EJP: That depends on the actual implementation. Whether a block is pooled or returned to the OS depends on various factors, one of them being the OS.

Comment: @Arkku Read, write order actually doesn't matter here. I am not writing the same number of bytes I am reading every time.

Comment: What is the problem? You have to initialize dynamic memory anyway, as it is not guaranteed to be zeroed by `malloc`.

Comment: @Olaf I was under the impression that malloc is used in C++ as well. There is no problem, just curiosity that is it possible for malloc to behave like this or i am doing something wrong while reading/writing?

Comment: In C++, you would normally use `new` which can be overloaded. Whether _that_ uses `malloc` in turn is a different question. However, your code is not valid C++, as C++ requires to cast `void *` - which you should **not** do in C. Both for reasons of type-checking actually.

Comment: @j29392 If you are reading more bytes than were written, those bytes should include a length to convey this information so that you don't access the ones that weren't written.

Comment: @Olaf It applies to every implementation I have ever used, including my own, over a period of more than thirty years.

Comment: "*I want to clear all the data structures before it starts a new message. So I just free the pointers and mallo them back.*" if the size allocated does not change, this approach is inefficient and useless, as you need to initialise the freshly allocated memory anyways (in one way or the other).

Comment: Just to be clear, because no one has explicitly said it: **You must not, under any circumstances, rely on malloc() returning the same memory you just free()d**. That would be undefined behavior and an invitation to horrific bugs.

Comment: @alk Yeah i agree its inefficient. Memset() is much better option!

Comment: @EOF I am not expecting it to return same pointer, i want to avoid it!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid getting the same memory again? You're not supposed to care. Also, a C program *cannot* avoid this, because you can't even compare the newly `malloc()`ed pointer to the `free()`d pointer. You might chose a C-library that goes above and beyond the requirements of C though. AFAIK, `openBSD`'s `malloc()` can do something like you ask for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is entirely possible.  When you call free, the memory manager will mark that section of memory as a fragment, possibly combining it with an adjacent fragment, but it will not set the data to all zeroes.  The `malloc()` function also does not set all the data to all zeroes.

If, for example, the `free()` is called for the first time in your program and immediately followed by a `malloc()` for an equal or lesser amount of memory, it's entirely possible that the memory manager will reuse the old fragment.

Comment: I think its an open and shut case then!! Thanks!

Comment: Worth clarifying that this is likely in practice, and that the standard allows for it, but that this is implementation-specific behaviour.